# Execute multiple hibernate dependencies criteria

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

Firstly, I am very new in hibernate so I don't have any idea how to working with multiple criteria.

Basically I have two criteria.

First criteria with sub query and I am defining this criteria as below :

```
DetachedCriteria subCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(RejectListTable.class, "rejectTable");
      subCriteria.add(Restrictions.like("rejectTable.rej_status", "R"));
      subCriteria.setProjection(Projections.property("rejectTable.roll_no"));
      //      subCriteria.setProjection(Projections.property("rejectTable.error_type"));

      String[] omrErrorsList = { "T", "U" };
      Criteria outerCriteria = session.createCriteria(OMRDetailsTable.class, "omrDetails");
      outerCriteria.add(Restrictions.in("omrDetails.omr_error", omrErrorsList));
      outerCriteria.add(Subqueries.notIn("omrDetails.roll_no", subCriteria));      

      List outerResults = outerCriteria.list();
```

2nd Criteria :

```
Criteria innerCriteria = session.createCriteria(SetWiseQuesDetailTable.class, "setWiseQuesDetailTable");
        innerCriteria.add(Restrictions.like("setWiseQuesDetailTable.set_nm", "A"));
        List innerResults = innerCriteria.list();
```

In the 2nd criteria "setWiseQuesDetailTable.set_nm" this value come from the 1st criteria. That means 2nd criteria depends on the 1st criteria data.

Right now in the 2nd criteria  "setWiseQuesDetailTable.set_nm" set static value "A" but actually its coming from 1st criteria.

So my question is that how to do that?

I have tried to used the above two criteria as below which is working slow.

```
  DetachedCriteria subCriteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(RejectListTable.class, "rejectTable");
  subCriteria.add(Restrictions.like("rejectTable.rej_status", "R"));
  subCriteria.setProjection(Projections.property("rejectTable.roll_no"));
  //         subCriteria.setProjection(Projections.property("rejectTable.error_type"));

  String[] omrErrorsList = { "T", "U" };
  Criteria outerCriteria = session.createCriteria(OMRDetailsTable.class, "omrDetails");
  outerCriteria.add(Restrictions.in("omrDetails.omr_error", omrErrorsList));
  outerCriteria.add(Subqueries.notIn("omrDetails.roll_no", subCriteria));  
  outerCriteria.addOrder(Order.asc("omrDetails.bar_code_no"));

  List outerResults = outerCriteria.list();  
  Iterator<OMRDetailsTable> outerIterator = outerResults.iterator();


  System.out.println(outerResults.size());
  Criteria innerCriteria = session.createCriteria(SetWiseQuesDetailTable.class, "setWiseQuesDetailTable");

  while(outerIterator.hasNext()){
    System.out.println("Outer Loop"+outerIterator.next().getBar_code_no());  
    innerCriteria.add(Restrictions.like("setWiseQuesDetailTable.set_nm", "A"));
    List innerResults = innerCriteria.list(); 
    Iterator<SetWiseQuesDetailTable> innerIterator = innerResults.iterator();
    while(innerIterator.hasNext()) {
      System.out.println("Inner loop"+innerIterator.next().getSet_nm());
    }  

    System.out.println("Outer Loop");
  }
```

How to improve the performance?

Comment: if you have not done so already, look at the generated sql (find out how to set the logging parameters for that), this might give a hint.

Comment: I have tried to used criteria... As you can see the my attempt. My attempted work fine but problem is that working slow. I am not getting idea why its working slow. Can please tell me what I missed?

Comment: I am sorry, I should have read better your question; looking at sql generated by Hibernate might help when the problem is not obvious from the code, but in your case it looks like Hibernate is making a query, and then for each of the results, you make another query (innerCriteria.list() inside the loop). You should instead try to get all the results with one query (so that in sql generated by Hibernate you will see a JOIN).